# Storing Unicode strings to SQLite database using PeeWee

Tags: python, string, sqlite, unicode, encoding

Working with peewee to create a simple sqlite database that stores items form a parsed MRSS feed, specifically video URLs and video titles.

I have a little dedupe script that I wrote that checks whether or not the URL and video title that's just been parsed is already in the database. I've noticed that when I pass URL strings to the database, there are no issues, dedupe works fine. When I browser through the database for the URLs I've stored there, using an app like [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org), I see the URLs with no Unicode encoding, they looks like regular old strings, no `u'`.

However, when I pass unicode video titles — like this: `(u'Animals doing the strangest things',)` the dedupe script wasn't "seeing" the video titles in the database. The solution was to do a simple conversion with the video title object like this:  `videoName = str(videoName)` — however, I have no clue why this works now. When I browse the videoName column in my database using sqlitebrowser, I see the video names, but they're still in Unicode and look the same as they did before: `(u'Animals doing the strangest things',)`

Any idea what the heck is going on here? Does this have something to do with a weird bug with how PeeWee is handling string serialization?

Answer (score 1):

Peewee uses unicode for both `CharField` and `TextField`, meaning that whatever value you have stored on your model is converted to a Python `unicode` object (well, `unicode` in Py2, `str` in Py3).

The database driver (`sqlite3`, `psycopg2`, etc) generally handles converting the unicode to the appropriate encoding.

I'm not sure what the bug is you're describing, but maybe you can share some code to replicate it. I can tell you though, that peewee's unicode handling is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what do you think would account or PeeWee not allowing me to store the video names stored in `videoName` until I altered it to `str(videoName)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowing"? Is there an error?

Comment: Only when I altered the unicode string held in videoName to str(videoName) would it show up in the SQLite database.